# how to get a ref key from a ref then search by the key and get data from that ref

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

i want to read the post's data and get the user key then search by it and get the user data at the same time , and i tried that but it is taking a step back and it doesn't show the user name until i do any other action

here is the firebase real-time database of the posts and the authenticated users

[image]
[image]

and here is the code i tried

```
userFullName = ''
    listenForCommunityAndPosts = () =>  {
        try {

            firebase.database().ref('posts').orderByChild('communityKey')
            .equalTo('-M07uNj9HbQxc_ich644'/*this.props.navigation.getParam("communityKey")*/)
            //.startAt('-M07uNj9HbQxc_ich644'/this.props.navigation.getParam("communityKey")/)
            .on('value', (dataSnapshot) =>{
                var postsList = [];
                dataSnapshot.forEach((child) => {
                    var userId = child.val().user
                    /**************/
                    firebase.database().ref('authenticatedUsers').child(userId).on('value', snap => {this.userFullName =  snap.val().fullName})
                    /**************/
                    postsList.push({
                        image: child.val().image,
                        text: child.val().text,
                        //user: child.val().user,
                        user: this.userFullName,
                        likesNumber: child.val().likesNumber,
                        commentsNumber: child.val().commentsNumber,
                        postKey: child.key
                    })
                })
                this.setState({ posts: postsList })
            })
        }
        catch(e){
            alert(e.message)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You now call `setState` when the `posts` have loaded, which is before the user name of each user is loaded. So your app will show the users without the user names.

To ensure it shows the posts with user names, you'll want to call `setState` when all user names have loaded. That's look something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('posts').orderByChild('communityKey')
.equalTo('-M07uNj9HbQxc_ich644')
.on('value', (dataSnapshot) =>{
    let promises = [];
    dataSnapshot.forEach((child) => {
        var userId = child.val().user
        let userRef = firebase.database().ref('authenticatedUsers').child(userId);
        promises.push(userRef.child('fullName').once('value'));
    })

    Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
        return snapshots.map((userNameSnapshot) => userNameSnapshot.val());
    }).then((userNames) => {
        let postsList = [];
        let index = 0;
        dataSnapshot.forEach((child) => {
            postsList.push({
                image: child.val().image,
                text: child.val().text,
                user: userNames[index],
                likesNumber: child.val().likesNumber,
                commentsNumber: child.val().commentsNumber,
                postKey: child.key
            })
            index = index + 1;
        });

        this.setState({ posts: postsList })
    });
```

What I changed:

- The user is now loaded with a `once()` listener, instead of with `on()`. This ensures you don't add another copy of the post if for example the user name changes. Note that you **can** handle such situations, but in that case you'll want to update the existing entry in `postsList`, instead of adding a new copy.
- The listener now only loads the user's name, since that is all you're using. This will reduce the bandwidth usage.
- It puts all the load operations into a `promises` array, and then uses `Promise.all` to "wait" for all of them to complete.
- Puts all the user names into a `userNames` array, in the same order as they are in the `dataSnapshot`.
- Builds the `postsList` based on the `dataSnapshot` and the `userNames` array.
- Puts the resulting list into the state, so that React renders it.

---

It's worth considering whether you want to call `setState` multiple times.

For example: once when the posts have loaded, and then once when each name comes back. That way you'd initially see the posts without user names, and then see each user name appear as it is loaded.

Alternatively, you could only add each post once its user name is posted. So in that case, you wouldn't call `setState` after loading the posts, but only after each post's user name is loaded.

Both of these are valid alternatives, that you can implement with a variation on the code above.